# Get photo from photo library

Tags: iphone

I use below code for get photo from photo library but with this code i can get photo that exist in save photo not all photo that exist in photo library

```
-(void)addphoto
{
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
 [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 UIImage *takephoto = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
 [self srAdd:takephoto];
}//imagePuckerController
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
- (IBAction)getImageAction {
self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];}
```

works for me

Comment: Thank you and how to take photo from camera?

Comment: [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
  self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This will let you take a photo with the camera or choose from library. It handles the whole process for you.

https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake